# Graph Layout Algorithms for JGraphT

Tags: jgrapht, graph-drawing, jgraph

I'm using JGraphT to create a graph and I want to be able to visualise and manipulate it. There are some examples that show how to visualise the graph, but it seems that it involves quite a lot of manual code to layout the vertices, etc.
I was wondering if there was any graph layout algorithm that could automate this process already in JGraph with a small example. Mostly the graphs I'm drawing are Directed Acyclic Graphs.
I have already drawn the graphs by exporting them to .dot format and display it using [dot](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dot), but I need a little interaction now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since JGraph seems to now be mxGraph, but JGraphT embed JGraph 5.13, it's not that easy but I've found [this doc](http://touchflow.googlecode.com/hg-history/75fada644b2a19c744130923cbd34747fba861a2/doc/jgraphmanual.pdf)
 and the following piece of code is working:

```
    // this a a JGraphT graph
    ListenableDirectedGraph<TableColumn, DefaultEdge> dependencyGraph = getDependencyGraph();

    JGraphModelAdapter adapter = new JGraphModelAdapter(dependencyGraph);

    JGraph jgraph = new JGraph(adapter);


    JGraphLayout layout = new JGraphHierarchicalLayout(); // or whatever layouting algorithm
    JGraphFacade facade = new JGraphFacade(jgraph);
    layout.run(facade);
    Map nested = facade.createNestedMap(false, false);
    jgraph.getGraphLayoutCache().edit(nested);

    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jgraph);
    this.add(sp);
```